# XML parsing removes information from list after completion

Tags: xml, python-3.x

I am using the following code to parse an XML

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import iterparse

# Read xml file
configTree = iterparse('../../SamdConfigurationMainEndat_Hi_LUT.xml', ['start', 'end'])

depth = 0
skipNode = False
parseNodes = ['Actuator', 'Sensor', 'AxisControl', 'ControlNetwork']
level = []
signals = []

for (event, node) in configTree:
    n = n + 1
    if event == 'end':
        if node.tag == 'Alignment':
            skipNode = False
        print(node.tag, signals[-3:-1])
        if node.tag in parseNodes:
            level.pop()
        depth -= 1

    # skip alignment node and only process when node start
    if skipNode is False and event == 'start':
        # check only parseNodes tag and level information
        if node.tag in parseNodes:
            # add elem level information
            if node.get('Name'):
                level.append(node.get('Name'))
            else:
                level.append(node.tag)
            print(depth*'*', node.tag, skipNode, event, level)
        elif node.tag == 'Signal':
            signalValue = {node.get('Name'): node.text}
            elem = [level, signalValue]
            signals.append(elem)            
            print(depth*'=', node.tag, level, signalValue)  
        else:
            print(depth*'+', node.tag)

    if event == 'start':
        if node.tag == 'Alignment':
            skipNode = True
        depth += 1
```

The output is stored in the **signals** list.
The output of **signals** list is does not contain **level** information but is visible in the print statements during the execution of the code.

What is causing the level information to disappear from the signals list?

Comment: Please post a snippet of XML file and desired output. We can't simply look at your code and know what you are attempting as we know nothing of node structure.

Comment: Well, I changed the code a bit. Seems to me that the list `level` appended to list `elem` is just a reference and updates with each change of `level`. So now using string.